# Running regrex_replace on Variable in Hive

Tags: hive

I am changing a date string in hive from `2017-02-21T11:28:36` to `2017-02-21 11:28:36` using the following command.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('2017-02-21T11:28:36', 'T', " ");
```

Output is coming correctly as `2017-02-21 11:28:36`. Now my input date string is stored in `READ_START_DATE` variable.

```
hive>SET READ_START_DATE;                                                   
READ_START_DATE=2017-02-21T11:28:36
```

Now I am running This command

```
SELECT regexp_replace('${READ_START_DATE}', 'T', " ");
```

Output of this command is `${READ_S AR _DA E}`

It make sense, but I need to run `regrex_replace` command on a variable. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${**hiveconf**:READ_START_DATE}
[LanguageManual VariableSubstitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution#LanguageManualVariableSubstitution-UsingVariables)

```
hive> set READ_START_DATE=2017-02-21T11:28:36;
hive> select regexp_replace('${hiveconf:READ_START_DATE}', 'T', " ");
OK
_c0
2017-02-21 11:28:36
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes

```
SELECT regexp_replace("${READ_START_DATE}", 'T', " ");
```

it's working with a different env variable but not sure why not with "READ_START_DATE", dudu any idea?

```
hive (default)> set system:java.vm.version;
system:java.vm.version=24.65-b04
hive (default)> select regexp_extract("${system:java.vm.version}",'.*?-(.*)');
OK
_c0
b04
Time taken: 0.076 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: it worked with a different variable, so suggested it, anyway, the above answer is much versatile, below is my try                                                                                                         hive (default)> set system:java.vm.version;
system:java.vm.version=24.65-b04
hive (default)> select regexp_extract("${system:java.vm.version}",'.*?-(.*)');
OK
_c0
b04
Time taken: 0.076 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)